# Error while preprocessing images with pretrained model in Tensorflow.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'applications' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to take an image from the page and preprocess it before passing it to the model (which is based on VGG19 architecture). When I try to use the provided vgg19 preprocessing application, I receive an error from Java : "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'applications' of undefined"

Am I calling the vgg19 function appropriately? I tried different versions of tf.js as well, to no avail.

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>Architectural Style Classifier 1.3</p>

<img id="imgcanvas" height="300" src='testimage1.jpg'></img>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
async function run(){
  const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgcanvas);
  const batchedImage = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input(image);
  const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/model.json';
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  const result = model.predict(batchedImage);
  result.print();
}
run();
</script>
</html>
```

The webpage if you'd like to try it yourself:

https://areddy831.github.io/

Or the github repository with the html file: https://github.com/areddy831/areddy831.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was trying to use a python module - vgg19 pre-processing is not available in tensorflow.js